# Broken Wi-Fi and Ethernet - Reinstalling OS X El Capitan

Tags: macos, wifi, hardware, mac-pro

Recently on my mid 2009 MacBook Pro, the Wi-Fi suddenly stopped working. I tried resetting NVRAM and SMC but to no avail. I thought it may be a hardware fault, but before buying a costly Airport card, I thought of trying to re-install the OS again.

I'm not able to get into recovery mode as it takes an unreasonably long duration of time (perhaps infinite) in opening. It hasn't opened even after waiting for hours.

Since my Wi-Fi is not working and the ethernet port is not detected, I don't know how to download the OS to reinstall.

How do I recover out of this situation?

Currently running OS X El Capitan 10.11.6.

Comment: 1. Do you have access to a working Mac that you can borrow? 2. Can you visit an Apple store nearby?

Comment: No this is the only mac from all people I know, however I have various windows PC/Laptops of my friends

Comment: Unfortunately a PC/Linux box won't do. You'll need a Mac to download the installer or to optionally create the bootable installer (if you wish to perform a clean install). You can visit with your MacBook to an Apple retail store and get assistance with aforementioned.

Comment: Ok, thank you for your reply sir, I'll try that way but I doubt whether service center will accept such old product or not.

Comment: WiFi and Ethernet issue can be overcome with a USB dongle.  However, your Mac doesn't support [Internet recovery](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202313) so you *need* an installer.  Do you have the original installation DVD?  Did you make a Time Machine backup?  If you can get to an Apple store, they can assist you in creating a USB installer or even reinstall the OS for you.

Comment: No DVD was lost long ago, I tried via my android Bluetooth tethering but it is painfully slow and it is far too lengthy way to download 4-5GB of data.